# Methods in async are calling in wrong order

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm

my methods which I'm using to management database didn't work in right order.
Database close method is calling before clearing method.

```
export const connection = {
  async close() {
    await getConnection().close()
  },

  async clear() {
    const connection = getConnection();
    const tNames = ["here I have names of tables"];

    tNames.forEach(async (table) => {
      await connection.query(`delete from [${table}]`);
    });
  },
};
```

I'm using jest to test my server and when I'm using these methods in afterAll() calling order is wrong.
Why closing method is before clear?

```
afterAll(async () => {
  await connection.clear();
  await connection.close();
});
```

Comment: using `await` in `.forEach()` doesn't wait until each iteration finishes, it just creates a bunch of pending promises before any of them is settled. Conversely, you cannot `await` something that calls a `.forEach()` with an async callback. You should be using `Promise.all` with map or an actual loop, depending on whether you prefer those to be resolved sequentially or in parallel.

Comment: Many thanks, now  I understand this. You're my hero!